Infinite ngx-slick-carousel with mat-icons - svg content disappear
I'm creating a carousel with help of the ngx-slick-carousel. Each of the slides contains a Material Card and within each card there are Material icons. When the carousel is not infinite, everything works as expected. However, when the carousel is infinite, once I reach the last slide and continue sliding right, the icons disappear. Actually the  tag stays when I inspect the DOM but  within it's content is missing. If I keep scrolling when I get to the first slide the icons appear again and the cycle repeats itself.
Any suggestions how to resolve this?
PS. I noticed that this happens only if I have registered the SVG icons like this: this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('star', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/icons/star.svg'));. If I register them like this.iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral('thumbs-up', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(THUMBUP_ICON)); they do not disappear.
Stackblitz sample -> here


Stackblitz missing :( please update it!

sry, updated :)
